# How to install Openshot 2.0 side by side with 1.4.3?

Tags: software-installation, openshot

I'd like to install Openshot 2.0 separately from 1.4.3 (say in opt, for example).

I'd tried running the appImage but it doesn't work due to incompatible libraries (weird for a self-contained application, I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of recently (since the time of posting the question) Openshot 2.0.x can now be installed (via the libopenshot ppa) side by side with 1.4.x.